Pytest not finding tests on Pycharm
I'm having this problem with pytest where pytest is not discovering my tests. I made sure I put the right directory in Python, set default test runner to pytest, set up file paths and directory in configuration and the pytest is running just not finding the results. I made sure I have the right naming conventions too, can someone help with this problem? I can't post images because it says I need reputation 10.
tried everything I can made sure things were right according to online info but didn't work

Show us your test source code, your directory layout, and the output of $ pytest *.py
